# ArgumentOutOfRangeException on changed colletion

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, locking

```
//I have collection
private static List<Sport> ChosenSports = new List<Sport>();

//and lock object for it 
private static object _lockSports = new object();

//I have checkbox that add or remove collection items
private void CheckBoxSportZone_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var chkZone = sender as CheckBox;
    lock (_lockSports)
    {
        if (chkZone.IsChecked == true)
            ChosenSports.Add(chkZone.DataContext as Sport);
        else if (chkZone.IsChecked == false)
            ChosenSports.Remove(chkZone.DataContext as Sport);
    }
}

//And method that uses that collection
private IEnumerable<Sport> FilterSports(HashSet<Sport> sports)
{
    lock (_lockSports)
        return sports. Where(x => ChosenSports.Contains(x));
}
```

When i check checkBox Filter method throw

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative
>   and less than the size of the collection.

Looks like I mark ChechBox in time of Checking Collection. But I'm using lock keyword, so it should be safe, isn't it?

Comment: Just out of curiosity...does it work if you refactor so you don't use a lambda in your lock, i.e. turn it into a block instead of a single line and do a loop to build the resulting collection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code:

```
private IEnumerable<Sport> FilterSports(HashSet<Sport> sports)
{
    lock (_lockSports)
        return sports. Where(x => ChosenSports.Contains(x));
}
```

only locks the instantiation of the Linq expression. The lock will have gone away by the time that the expression is actually enumerated.

You should probably cause the `ChosenSports` collection to be iterated inside the lock (and return a copy of the enumeration), by calling `.ToArray()` like so:

```
private IEnumerable<Sport> FilterSports(HashSet<Sport> sports)
{
    lock (_lockSports)
        return sports.Where(x => ChosenSports.Contains(x)).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Right, this is what I was alluding to in my comment under the question.

Comment: @roryap Yep, I reckon that's what the problem is. It's something that's bitten me in the past!